# Text over image, without affecting other texts on image

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an image where 3 words are on, but I can't get the 3rd on it because it will not go in the `position` I want it. Here's the picture with words.

```css
#clubname {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 26%;
    color: #FFF;
 line-height: 0px;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
}
#pacoins {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 84px;
    margin-left: 13%;
 max-width:5%;
 max-height:5%;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
    font-size: 17px;
}
#myclub {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30%;
    line-height: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://packsimulator.nl/img/PAClubCover.png" style="position:absolute;">
<a href="#profile"><p id="clubname">Julan FC</p></a>
<a href="#pacoins"><p id="pacoins">97.000</p></a>
<a href="#club"><p id="myclub">My Club</p></a>
```

As you can see 'My Club' isn't after the blue icon. Where it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap these with a container/wrap `div` then use `position:relative/absolute`

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width:400px /* width of image */
}
img {
  position: absolute
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 0;
  font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 17px
}
#clubname {
  left: 40%;
}
#pacoins{
  left: 25%;
  top:22px;
}
#myclub {
  left: 55%;
  top:22px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://packsimulator.nl/img/PAClubCover.png" />
  <a href="#profile">
    <p id="clubname">Julan FC</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#pacoins">
    <p id="pacoins">97.000</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#club">
    <p id="myclub">My Club</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Way more elegant than mine.  But, this is why I participate.  Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `float:left;`.

Change your css to be like this

```
#pacoins {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    max-width: 5%;
    max-height: 5%;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
    font-size: 17px;
    float:left;
}
#myclub {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 42%;
    line-height: 84px;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
}
```

Working JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/dotcgtuc/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't take into consideration browser window sizing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to position it with `position: absolute;`. For example

```css
#clubname {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 26%;
    color: #FFF;
 line-height: 0px;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
}
#pacoins {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 84px;
    margin-left: 13%;
 max-width:5%;
 max-height:5%;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
    font-size: 17px;
}
#myclub {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 45px;
    line-height: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://packsimulator.nl/img/PAClubCover.png" style="position:absolute;">
<a href="#profile"><p id="clubname">Julan FC</p></a>
<a href="#pacoins"><p id="pacoins">97.000</p></a>
<a href="#club"><p id="myclub">My Club</p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have a couple things going on here that aren't quite recommended, but with reworking your html & css I believe I've produced the result you're looking for.

First, you're embedding paragraph tags `<p>` in anchor tags `<a>` - this is only HTML5 compatible because the p is a block element while anchor is inline.  I'd suggest using span tags how you have it.

Secondly, your CSS uses percentages to place these elements - so once a browser resize takes place, your elements will all be thrown off.  Putting this information together, I believe we can achieve the results you are looking for:

**CSS**

```
#clubname {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 255px;
    color: #FFF;

    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
}
#pacoins {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 100px;
    max-width:5%;
    max-height:5%;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
    font-size: 17px;
}
#myclub {
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 32px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Knul-Bold';
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://packsimulator.nl/img/PAClubCover.png" style="position:absolute;">
<a href="#profile"><span id="clubname">Julan FC</span></a>
<a href="#pacoins"><span id="pacoins">97.000</span></a>
<a href="#club"><span id="myclub">My Club</span></a>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aw6hqt8u/1/)